# Select bookings between 2 dates, even though they did not end yet

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to display reservations/bookings details that are between two dates.

I have this calendar :
[image]

If I select, that I want to see details of reservations that are "happening" between dates 2020-06-09 and 2020-06-11, I want to get both of the reservations (blue and red). I mean, that it does not matter when the reservation has been made or when it is supposed to end, if it is or was active between those 2 dates, it should be displayed.

So what I need to achieve:
If I select I want to display reservations between dates 2020-06-09 and 2020-06-11, I should get back both red (2020-06-10 --- 2020-06-12) and blue (2020-06-08 --- 2020-06-12) reservations.

Right now I have this MySQL query but it does not seem to work correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE CONVERT('2020-06-09', DATE) BETWEEN booked_from

AND booked_until AND CONVERT('2020-06-11', DATE) BETWEEN  booked_from AND booked_until
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you are looking to get any database record where the end date is after 2020-06-09 and the start date is before 2020-06-11.  This will select any booking that overlaps with your date range, whether it starts before and ends in the range, starts in and ends after the range, starts before and ends after the range, or starts and ends inside the range.  In all of these cases, it starts before you're later date and ends after your earlier date.  So try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE STR_TO_DATE('2020-06-09', '%Y-%m-%d') <= booked_until AND STR_TO_DATE('2020-06-11', '%Y-%m-%d') >= booked_from
```

Note: I've replaced the `CONVERT` function with the more explicit `STR_TO_DATE` function, but your final query may vary slightly depending on the database your using it on and what schema you're using.

Answer (score -3):

if you use a query like below it might work for you:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Bookings 
WHERE (DATE(booked_from) 
  BETWEEN DATE('2020-06-09) 
  AND DATE('2020-06-11)) 
AND (DATE(booked_until) 
  BETWEEN DATE('2020-06-09) 
  AND DATE('2020-06-11))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it answers the question.[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)